# How to debug str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

How can I debug str_replace?

I have this code:

```
$mit = array('[ID]','[IDvege]','[URL]','[DATUM]');
$mire = array("[".$i['id']."]","[/".$i['id']."]","http://teddfel.hu/sitemaps/maps/".$i['id'].".xml",$i['last_mod']);
$tartalom = str_replace($mit,$mire,$tartFile);
```

This is the content of $tartFile:

```
<!-- [ID] -->               
   <sitemap>
      <loc>[URL]</loc>
      <lastmod>[DATUM]</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
<!-- [IDvege] -->
```

However after str_replace $tartalom is empty.

Comment: Enable error reporting

Comment: Can you show us your loop (assuming there is a `for` loop somewhere which uses `$i` - problem may be there?

Comment: Are you reading in your file correctly?  Try to see if $tartFile is actually the string that you think it is. (Your code worked fine for me passing it in as a string)

Comment: I'm reading file with: file_get_contents(); 
$le = mysql_query('SELECT * from sitemaps order by id DESC');
while ($i = mysql_fetch_assoc($le))
{
...
}

Comment: print your result from file_get_contents() just to ensure that it is reading properly.

also, it is possible that your query is returning 0 results - so make sure that it is actually executing the str_replace. (just print the array from the query to test)

Comment: OMG, that was it. It was an empty query...